# How to rewrite this code from python loops to numpy vectors (for perfomance)?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, vectorization

I have this code:

```
for j in xrange (j_start, self.max_j):
   for i in xrange (0, self.max_i):
      new_i = round (i + ((j - j_start) * discriminant))
      if new_i >= self.max_i:
         continue 
      self.grid[new_i, j] = standard[i]
```

and I want to speed it up by throwing away slow native python loops. There is possibility to use numpy vector operations instead, they are really fast. How to do that?

```
j_start, self.max_j, self.max_i, discriminant
```

int, int, int, float (constants).

```
self.grid
```

two-dimensional numpy array (self.max_i x self.max_j).

```
standard
```

one-dimensional numpy array (self.max_i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete solution, perhaps that will help.

```
jrange = np.arange(self.max_j - j_start)
joffset = np.round(jrange * discriminant).astype(int)
i = np.arange(self.max_i)

for j in jrange:
    new_i = i + joffset[j]
    in_range = new_i < self.max_i
    self.grid[new_i[in_range], j+j_start] = standard[i[in_range]]
```

It may be possible to vectorize both loops but that will, I think, be tricky.

I haven't tested this but I believe it computes the same result as your code.